# why is qt4 package needed to run vlc player?

Tags: arch-linux, dependencies, vlc

I installed arch linux. As a video player i choose vlc.
i couldn't run vlc unless i installed qt4 package. Why is it needed ?
If we can't run vlc without qt4 pkg why is it not installed along with vlc.
Can anybody help me understand it ?

Comment: Please do let me know if i did anything wrong while installing vlc.
I used 'pacman -Syu vlc' command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Arch Linux, if you execute `pacman -Qi vlc`, it shows you a list of Dependencies for `vlc` (among other information), and another list of Optional Dependencies. If you take a look at that list, there is an entry that says `qt4: for the GUI`.

When you install a package, pacman normally tells you what the optional dependencies are for that package. Be sure to read through these, so that you don't miss anything!

The reason that `qt4` is optional (as opposed to mandatory) is that the vlc package provides you with the commands `vlc` and `cvlc`. `vlc` is the command for starting the graphical VLC you know already. With `cvlc` however, you can play a music file from your command line without opening a GUI. Because parts of the vlc package work without installing `qt4`, it's only listed as an optional dependency.

Comment: Thanks, my concerns was what is the use of vlc without gui. Didn't thought it could be used only for music.

Comment: still doesnt make any sense. vlc is a compiled binary, why would there ever be the need for qt libraries? this almostlooks like a dependency error

Comment: Also, vlc can act as a streaming server or convert/rip media, none of which requires the GUI. You might be using the features on a server that doesn't even have a graphical display.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that it requires Qt itself?  When testing on my system, it does not show that dependency:

```
$ apt depends vlc | grep qt

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

  Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1)
 |Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2)
  Depends: libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2)
  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0)
  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0)
```

Requiring Qt *libraries* is not the same as requiring Qt *itself*.  If this is different in Arch, you might want to contact the maintainer of the Qt package in the relevant Arch repository.

Comment: Thanks, Yes vlc requires qt4 for the GUI,
'pacman -Qi vlc' gives qt4[for the GUI] in optional deps. I will gather more info about qt later on.